# Keycloak Integration with a Linux Server

Tags: linux, ssh, pam, keycloak

I've set up a Keycloak server and I'm working on integrating it with a Linux server to allow users from Keycloak to authenticate into the Linux server using their Keycloak credentials.

Ideally, I'd like it so that when users run the `ssh server-name@server-ip` command, it opens a Keycloak login page where they can enter their credentials and gain access to the system.

My research led me to explore PAM as a way to configure Keycloak integration with a linux server. I installed kc-ssh-pam binary and added the following line to the /etc/pam.d/sshd directory:

```bash
auth sufficient pam_exec.so expose_authtok log=/var/log/kc-ssh-pam.log /opt/kc-ssh-pam/kc-ssh-pam
```

After that, I edited the **config.toml** file with my Keycloak configurations as shown below, and ran `sudo systemctl restart sshd`  to restart the ssh daemon. However, I'm not achieving the expected result when I run the ssh server-name@server-ip command.

```bash
realm = "realm_name"
endpoint = "https://keycloak_server_url"
clientid = "ssh_client_id"
clientsecret = "ssh_client_secret"
clientscop = "openid"
```

Is this an ideal use case? I have limited resources to accomplish this, so I would appreciate any steps or recommended guides that could help me achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It will not open the keycloak page for user login, they way it works is that it gets password grant token from keycloak based on user credentials.

When you run ssh `server-name@server-ip` , the user must exist on `server-ip` machine before hand without any password or with it, this module does not create the user automatically.
However there is a script mentioned in the instructions which you can use to create the users automatically when you try to login for the first time.